# How to properly remove NaN values from table

Tags: matlab, nan

After reading an Excel spreadsheet in Matlab I unfortunately have NaNs included in my resulting table. So for example this Excel table:

[image: Excel table]

would result in this table:

[image: Matlab table]

where an additional column of NaNs occurs. I tried to remove the NaNs with the following code snippet:

```
measurementCells = readtable('MWE.xlsx','ReadVariableNames',false,'ReadRowNames',true);
measurementCells = measurementCells(any(isstruct(measurementCells('TIME',1)),1),:);
```

However this results in a `0x6` table, without any values present anymore. How can I properly remove the NaNs without removing any data from the table?

Comment: "Remove NaNs without removing data" is impossible by definition! What do you expect the result to look like? `Var5` and `Var6` are numerical type columns, so can't have blank elements, hence the NaNs. You could convert them to character arrays and have empty strings, but that seems like hassle to end up with data in an awkward data type. It would perhaps help to know *why* you want to remove the NaNs. **Your main issue is using `readtable` which outputs columns of constant variable type, when you want *rows* of constant variable type**

Comment: I can't reproduce your result (i.e. no extra column of NaNs). Make sure you don't have any whitespace in the 'G' column of your Excel file.

Comment: Don't remove NaNs but rather take them into account later. You have `isnan` function to check for NaNs. If you really want to remove NaNs you can substitute them with some value of your choice using argument pair ('EmptyValue', value) inside the function `readtable`

Comment: The main problem I'm facing with the NaNs is that I can't obtain one row of the data by measurementCells{{nameOfRow},:} because Matlab is then telling me that not all values in that row are of the same type as the NaNs seem to be of the type cell rather than being double NaNs. So a conversion of all NaNs to NaNs of the type double would also solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either this:

```
tab = tab(~any(ismissing(tab),2),:);
```

or:

```
tab = rmmissing(tab);
```

if you want to remove rows that contain one or more missing value.

If you want instead to replace missing values with other values, read about how `fillmissing` (https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fillmissing.html) and `standardizeMissing` (https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/standardizemissing.html) functions work. The examples are exhaustive and should help you to find the solution that best fits your needs.

One last solution you have is to spot (and manipulate in the way you prefer) `NaN` values within the call to the `readtable` function using the `EmptyValue` parameter. But this works only against numeric data.