# How to obtain rows of an incomplete Matlab table?

Tags: matlab, nan

After getting answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758228/how-to-properly-remove-nan-values-from-table) I realized that I do have a problem with importing data into Matlab but it has nothing to do with NaNs but rather with different data types stored in the table.

In the same example I used in the other question importing an Excel table

[image: Excel table]

using

```
measurementTable = readtable('MWE.xlsx','ReadVariableNames',false,'ReadRowNames',true);
```

leads to the Matlab table

[image: Matlab table]

As you can see the values in column 1 to 4 are of type cell while the values in column 5 are of type double. If I would now try to obtain a single row of the table by using

```
measurementTable{'DATE',:}
```

I get the error message:

> Cannot concatenate the table variables 'Var5' and 'Var1', because their types are double and cell.

How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: Try change your date to number, for example, 10.03.2017 to 20170310 and MATLAB will see all values as double. Also, the error may due to the F column in your EXCEL is missing date? Did you leave it blank on purpose?

Comment: Yes I did that on purpose because my real data also contains missing values in some instances. How can I change the values of the table before importing them? I don't want to include manual pre-processing in Excel in my workflow, because that would tremendously slow down the data evaluation.

Comment: In EXCEL, use find&replace to replace all values. You can either replace all empty values or replace all date.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not really an option because I need to post-process a rather large number of Excel files hence I would really like to automate the import in Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you worked out the command you are using is failing due to Matlab trying to combine the cells and doubles to an array.

Since you have multiple data types you need to store your "row" in a cell array.

You can obtain a single row of mixed data by doing:

```
table2cell ( measurementTable('DATE',:) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How could I then use the resulting cells to convert the date strings into the scalar datetime array with the datetime function. It seems like I can't use the cell array resulting from table2cell.

Comment: In reality this is a different question, so should be asked as one showing what you have tried to do.  help `datetime` should get you started.